# Apex Trigger On Knowledge Article Object After Publishing - In Lightning

Tags: trigger, lightning-experience, articles, lightning-knowledge

We have a requirement to update a field on the Knowledge article after the article is published.

But it seems that trigger does not fires after the Knowledge Article Published (i.e. PublishedStatus = Online).
As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_knowledge_considerations.htm), it is mentioned that the actions that change the publication status of a KAV record, such as Publish and Archive, do not fire Apex triggers. **However, sometimes publishing an article from the UI causes the article to be saved, and in these instances the before update and after update triggers are called.** (THIS LINE IS BIT CONFUSING)

Sample Code, what we want to do-

```
    List<Knowledge__kav> newListKnowledge = (List<Knowledge__kav>) trigger.new;
    for(Knowledge__kav newKnowledge : newListKnowledge) {
        if(String.isNotBlank(newKnowledge.FIELD_1) && newKnowledge.PublishStatus =='Online') {
             //do-something;
        }
    }
```

Batch apex is one of the option we can think, but
Is there any other workaround for this scenario?

Comment: No there is no workaround to this. You have to triggered the update manually via a scheduled job or batch.

Comment: @NagendraSingh, Thank you for the response.